# How to stop an audioclip when the condition is over?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity and I'm having some problems on adding audio in my enemies. I have an audio clip for walking, attacking and dying. But when I play the game the audioclips starts playing in the right condition, but they never stop like I was expecting. I want them to only play while they're in the right condition and stop playing when in another condition.

Here's my code:

```
public override void ActionCharacter(){

    if (!isDead) {

        currentTimeToChangeAction += Time.deltaTime;

        if (currentDistanceToPlayer <= distanceToAttack && currentTimeToAttack < timeToAttack) {
            currentTimeToAttack += Time.deltaTime;
            inAttack = true;
            axiVertical = 0;
            audio.PlayOneShot(ZombieWalkAudio);
            animationCharacter.CrossFade (attackAnimation.name);
        } else {
            currentTimeToAttack = 0;
            inAttack = false;
        }

        if (inStun) {
            currentTimeToStun += Time.deltaTime;
            if (currentTimeToStun > timeToStun) {
                currentTimeToStun = 0;
                inStun = false;
            }
            axiVertical = 0;
            animationCharacter.CrossFade (damageAnimation.name);
        }

        if (!inAttack && !inStun) {
            if (currentTimeToChangeAction > timeToChangeAction) {
                currentTimeToChangeAction = 0;
                //axiHorizontal = Time.deltaTime * walkVelocity;
                axiVertical = Time.deltaTime * walkVelocity;
                audio.PlayOneShot(ZombieAttackAudio);
            }

            if (currentDistanceToPlayer <= distanceMinToRun) {
                callRun = true;     
            } else {
                callRun = false;    
            }

            transform.LookAt (player.transform);
            //currentGun.Shoot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *only play **while** they're in the right condition* -> Have you considered a `while` loop? If yes: what makes this not a possibility?

Comment: I did. But using a loop inside a game code?

Comment: Is it looping constantly in the scene? For example, when they are in the walk state and die does the walking sound keep playing?

Comment: It's unclear. What is the problem? Do you want one sound to stop when another starts playing? Or what?

Comment: Exatcly, FuncionR. And the sound plays like it's in slow motion.

Comment: Yes, Sergey. But it doesn't happen.

Comment: i dont know how long your clips are but slow motion sounds to me like your playoneshot is firing every frame, any clip starting as a one shot every frame as an update is going to make an echo like slow motion like sound